# First attempt at understanding applet and runnable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I'm new to Java. I need help figuring out some of the code I'll be displaying below. The point of the code is to simply create an applet which displays a ball moving from left to right using a change in X position. I have began following a tutorial for applets from a website which made this code available to me (http://www.javacooperation.gmxhome.de/BallBewegungEng.html). Basically, I need someone to explain to the following methods and their contents: the start method (what is a thread? I'm aware it's an object, but what purpose does it serve here?). The run method (what exactly am I doing when I set the thread priority to MIN/MAX? Why does this method call the repaint() method even when no such method has been created?). Lastly, the paint method (what exactly is the g.fillOval line doing and how?). I've tried googling these things, but I'm having a hard time understanding understand the jargon that I see with most answers. I need things explained in a more simplistic way so that I may understand the jargon later on.

Thanks for any help in advance. The code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class MovingBall extends Applet implements Runnable
    {

       int x_pos = 10;
       int y_pos = 150;
       int radius = 20;

       public void init()
       {
          setBackground (Color.blue);
       }

       public void start()
       {
          Thread th = new Thread(this);
          th.start();
       }

       public void stop()
       {

       }

       public void destroy()
       {

       }

       public void run()
       {
          Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

          while(true)
          {
             x_pos++;

             repaint();

             try
             {
                Thread.sleep (20);
             }
             catch(InterruptedException ex)
             {

             }

             Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
          } 
       }

       public void paint (Graphics g)
       {
          g.setColor (Color.red);

          g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
       }

    }
```

Comment: *"I need help figuring out some of the code I'll be displaying below."*  It is AWT (obsolescent) and Applet (advanced) so ignore it and learn Java.  When you learn about Java GUIs, learn Swing or Java-FX (and avoid applets for a while even then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread is something you use when you want to run multiple pieces of code at the same time, without interrupting the other threads. In this case you use the thread to repaint the screen and pause the loop without affecting the rest of the program.

The run method is overriding from the Runnable object that you pass to the thread to run. When you create a thread, you pass it a runnable object with a run method defined, which will run when the thread starts.

The repaint method is not defined in this class, however it is defined in the parent class(Applet), so you can call it in this class just fine.

The paint method is overriding from Applet as well, so you are defining what the applet will do when it runs the paint method.

Comment: So "implements runnable" is class that we are implementing and passing to run()? and run is a method predefined within that class that we I am now overriding with the method defined here in this class? That kind of makes sense to me, but how exactly is runnable being passed on to run? Just by the fact that we are overriding it's own run method? And what about the priority?

Comment: Since your class implements runnable, and runnable has a method defined as run, when you call run in your class, it is overriding the runnable that you implementing. When you start your thread, it looks for the run method in the runnable that you pass it, and since you pass it your class, it will run the run method you override. And thread priority determines the cpu allocation between threads, the higher the priority, the more processing power it will have, and the faster it will run.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation, thank you so much. Your answer has been accepted and I'd vote you up if I could. Thank you.